# An Array Filled With Arrays Containing Data Structure

Tags: excel, vba

Want to avoid creating a class.

Only user-defined types defined in public object modules can be coerced to or from a variant or passed to late-bound functions

Only solution I see:

Create an array that is to be filled with arrays.
Create arrays that are to fill first array.
Fill first array with pointer to second arrays (I have functions for accessing elements to array once given pointer to header struct)

```
Private Type GameBoardCell
    Column       As Long
    Row          As Long
End Type

Sub testgameboard()
    Dim temparry() As GameBoardCell
    temparry = GameboardCellsInitalize
End Sub

Private Function GameboardCellsInitalize() As GameBoardCell()
Dim TempArrayRows()         As Variant
Dim TempArrayColumns()      As GameBoardCell
Dim GameBoardCell           As GameBoardCell
Dim Index                   As Long
Dim IndexTwo                As Long

    ReDim TempArrayRows(0 To 27)

    For Index = 0 To UBound(TempArrayRows)
        ReDim TempArrayColumns(0 To 51)
        For IndexTwo = 0 To UBound(TempArrayColumns)
            GameBoardCell.Column = IndexTwo + ColumnOffset
            GameBoardCell.Row = Index + RowOffset
            TempArrayRows(Index) = TempArrayColumns
        Next IndexTwo
    Next Index
    GameboardCellsInitalize = TempArrayRows
End Function
```

Comment: Why jump through so many hoops to avoid using classes? If you want quick n' dirty then you don't need the whole *`Property`-pair with a private backing field* gig; move these `Type` members to a class module as `Public` fields, e.g. `Public Column As Long`; `Public Row As Long`. And if you name the class `GameBoardCell`, your existing code won't even blink.